# Pandas:drop row from a dataframe based on a list disregarding the capital first letter

Tags: python, pandas

I need to remove from my dataframe the rows that in a column matches the string from a list.

I used `wo_list = df[~df.Match.isin(mylist)]`

The problem is that some strings have a capital first letter in the list but not in my df.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is convert both - column and list to lowercase:

```
mylist = ['Yui','Adf']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Match':['adf','ert','yui']})

wo_list = df[~df.Match.str.lower().isin([str(x).lower() for x in mylist])]
print (wo_list)
  Match
1   ert
```

Or you can use [`Series.str.capitalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html) for column for match list:

```
mylist = ['Yui','Adf']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Match':['adf','ert','yui']})

wo_list = df[~df.Match.str.capitalize().isin(mylist)]
print (wo_list)
  Match
1   ert
```

Comment: I also tried this but I get this error 'bool' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @tor_sten20 - Not sure, there is not some `()` mismatch ?

Comment: Don't think so, but the problem seems to be the list, if I try to lower the elements I get the same error

Comment: @tor_sten20 - second solution failed too?

Comment: @tor_sten20 - I think problem is some `True` boolean in list `mylist`

Comment: @tor_sten20 - Added `str` for convert values in list `mylist` to strings in first solution, then `True` boolean is converted to `true` like string